# PowerMockito: stub any new object of given type

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I have a  method implementing an authentification process with a server. If connecntion fails, the code will wait some time and then try again.
I want to test this method now, but I do not want to wait several minutes, so I think I have to stub the array, in which the waiting durations are stored.
Now the problem is that this array is a local variable somewhere deep down in my code and stubbing local variables doesn't work with Mockito/PowerMockito as far as I could find out. Also extracting the definition of the array to an own method does not work without things getting extremly messy.
My idea was now to just replace any newly created int array with a predfined array with shorter waiting times. Is there any possibility to do this?

This is the simplified code:

```
public class Foo {
    public void doFoo() {
        final Bar bar = Bar.createSpecialBar();
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar createSpecialBar(){
        Bar localBar = new Bar();
        Bar.doBar();
    }

    public Bar () {
    }

    public doBar() {
        int[] iWantToStubThisIntArray = {1000};
    }
}

public class TestFoo {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.doFoo();
    Assert.assertTrue(/*Some Condition*/);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: I can't, because I don't own any of it... i'm trying to replicate my problem in a simplified way

Comment: Just to be clear: you can't make changes to that code than? As you see, the reasonable answer would be to improve design/implementation.

Comment: I can, but I try to avoid it, since it would be likely to cause a lot of bugs if I do so. I've added a simplified version of the relevant code; have a look, if you want